# Is there a way to enable `-Wconversion` in nvcc for the device code (the kernel code)?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvcc

I am recently learning to write a prefix sum algorithm with CUDA. I had a stupid bug where I assigned a float variable to an integer variable losing precision:

```
// Phase 3: populate last element o previous subsection.
__shared__ float XY[SECTION_SIZE];
// ...
const int prev_sec_sum = ((subsection_idx > 0) ? XY[subsection_idx - 1] : 0.0f);
//    ^ Should be float here.
for (size_t i = 0; i < COARSEN_FACTOR - 1; i++) {
    XY[subsection_idx + i] += prev_sec_sum;
}
```

I should have been more careful about this, but I am surprised that `nvcc` does not warn about the conversion. I did a search then I realized that the following compiler flag is only for the host code:

```bash
--compiler-options -Wall,-Wextra,-Wconversion
```

After searching through the nvcc document, the only compiler flag I can find is `--Werror all-warnings` which does not generate any warning for this conversion. Do you know if `nvcc` supports this conversion checking? For example, do we have a `-Wconversion`-like flag for the device code?

I tired:

```bash
nvcc -o bin/prefix_sum prefix_sum.cu --compiler-options -Wall,-Wextra,-Wconversion --Werror all-warnings --compiler-bindir /usr/bin/gcc-12 -arch=native
```

But it only check conversion error for the host code.

Thanks for your help.

---

### Update:

Although not through `nvcc`, with the help from @paleonix, I can get a warning/error for it when building it with clang. Please see my post below.

I wonder if this means that only experts should use `nvcc` to build the program given that it lacks some basic checking functionality. My speculation is that as the native CUDA kit, it should generate faster code than clang using more optimization techniques.

Comment: You might be able to compile with CUDA-enabled clang for such warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I did not know that we can compile CUDA code with clang.

Comment: [Compiling CUDA with clang](https://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html) I have little experience with using it, so not sure what restrictions there are.

Comment: Personally I try to use `auto` as much as possible to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: It also somewhat pushes you to think about the type of the expression on the right of the `=` more, i.e. use `0.0f` instead of `0.0` which is a `double`.

Comment: @paleonix Thanks for the `auto` advice, I think my previous mindset was using the type of the variable to ensure the type matches. But with with `auto` the type correctness depends on the right part, this is good to know

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question and provide some reference for whom just started learning CUDA programming.

Thanks to the help from @paleonix, I used clang to build my CUDA program.

With build option `-Weverything -Werror`, I am now able to get the `-Wimplicit-int-float-conversion` error/warning from it.

For this code snippet:

```
// Phase 3: populate last element of previous subsection.
const int prev_sec_sum = ((subsection_idx > 0) ? XY[subsection_idx - 1] : 0.0f);
//    ^ Should be float here.
for (size_t i = 0; i < COARSEN_FACTOR - 1; i++) {
    XY[subsection_idx + i] += prev_sec_sum;
}
```

I used the following command:

```bash
clang++-18 -Weverything -Werror -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-unsafe-buffer-usage prefix_sum.cu -o bin/prefix_sum --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_89 -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart_static
```

This is the result:

```
prefix_sum.cu:467:51: error: implicit conversion turns floating-point number into integer: 'float' to 'const int' [-Werror,-Wfloat-conversion]
  467 |         const int prev_sec_sum = ((subsection_idx > 0) ? XY[subsection_idx - 1] : 0.0f);
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prefix_sum.cu:469:29: error: implicit conversion from 'const int' to 'float' may lose precision [-Werror,-Wimplicit-int-float-conversion]
  469 |                 XY[subsection_idx + i] += prev_sec_sum;
      |                                        ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated when compiling for sm_89.
```

which is exactly what I want.